# Form POST to 2 URLS

Tags: php, http, forms

I need to post a single form to 2 different URLs. One is just a logging script so the response doesn't need to be passed back to the user.

Unfortunately in this instance I can't just post to a single PHP script and turn around and re-POST it using Curl. This has to be done in the user's browser.

This is some Javascript I'm using right now but it's failing at a seemingly random rate for almost all the major browsers (but works 95%+ of the time). The rest of the form does require Javascript to function so I know the problem isn't just that some users have Javascript turned off.

```
  function makePOSTRequest(url, parameters) {

  http_request = false;

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...

     http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();

     if (http_request.overrideMimeType) {

        http_request.overrideMimeType('text/html');
     }
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
     try {
        http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
     } catch (e) {
        try {
           http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {}
     }
  }
  if (!http_request) {
     alert('Cannot create XMLHTTP instance');
     return false;
  }

  http_request.open('POST', url, true);
  http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameters.length);
  http_request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
  http_request.send(parameters);
```

}

I'm calling that after building the request manually in another function, then calling the submit() function of the form.

Can anyone suggest an alternative that might work better? This seems to be working ~95% of the time but that 5% failure rate is a killer... Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using jquery to manage your ajax requests?

Comment: Why don't you include log file in same file or process both in same file?if server is different,  do by php curl.

Comment: just as a hunch: try double clicking the form. some people tend to do that, it might fail one of the posts or duplicate them

Comment: Marzab might have it. We had double-click prevention on the form but it looks like it was removed at some point. I bet that's it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a framework that supports error checking any try repeating the request on failure.

JavaScript frameworks like jQuery support sending post requests and can be used to check if a request was successful. Also your code will be easier to write and maintain.

Comment: I should have included a note that I can't use jQuery in this instance either. Long story but trust me, I wish I could! I'm still going to go ahead and accept this as it is probably the best solution to the problem. That, and your suggestion about checking for double-click is likely the real culprit!